# How to Secure Wordpress website using .htaccess , allowing only index.php execution access

Tags: htaccess, security

I am responsible for security of lots of shared hosting server. We have at least 500 wordpress website in each server.

Some of the website owners keep a weak password for WP admin or use vulnerable plugin/themes, this results in injecting a WP sites with malware.

Once website is injected with malware, It is used for sending spam emails or some other malicious activity.

Though, we have instructed 100 times to keep a tough password, sometime people don't listen properly.

One of my friend told me that, We can block the execution of uploaded PHP file using .htaccess, i.e providing access only to index.php in public_html & wp-admin

```
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

**3 specific question about the problem**

1) How can I block the execution of all other php files, except index.php in public_html & wp-admin ?

2) What modification is needed in the above .htacess file ? (Assume I am going to place it in all sub-folders in public_html)

2) Allowing only index.php in public_html & wp-admin is sufficient for the wordpress to function properly ?

Comment: I am part of webmaster too, But i thought this is more suitable place.  If make sense, please move it.

Comment: Well I just dont see how this is really a WP issue when it involves the server but that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question and I think, I have found the answer.

The following code to be appended in .htaccess of public_html

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

<Files wp-login.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

The following code to be added in the .htaccess of wp-admin

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files admin-ajax.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files load-styles.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files load-scripts.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files edit.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files post-new.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files edit-tags.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files upload.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files media-new.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files edit-comments.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files admin.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files themes.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files widgets.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files plugins.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files customize.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files plugin-install.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files plugin-editor.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files plugin-install.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files plugin-install.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

I have tested & It is working fine in WordPresss. So that we can block the execution of other uploaded malicious file.

Let me know if it is wrong, Or does it work.

Or is there any other better way to do it.

Comment: if all you want to do is block execution, then you first need proper permissions at the file system. Anyway, what you are doing is blocking access and not execution and this usually amounts to the same thing except for the uploads directory where you will basically deny the upload of legal php files (not a biggy probably). What you ommit in a big way is all the other languages, script kiddies know how to use perl, not only php

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, but there is very little reason to actually do it.

What it may protect against is this case:

- an attacker can upload files with .php extension
- to an arbitrary directory (otherwise, you could just secure that one upload directory)
- but not with .htaccess extension (this would allow PHP execution via any file extension, such as png)
- and they cannot overwrite existing files (which would mean they could just overwrite eg an existing index.php file)
- and they cannot create subfolders (because they could upload a index.php file there)

This is a very narrow scenario. It's not impossible, so if you really think that you do need the added security, go ahead (this will not solve your spam problem though; for that, you would need to force better passwords, restrict the plugins users may install, and generally harden wordpress, also against those users). But it will likely cause more problems than it will solve, and it is not quite as easy to implement as it may seem.

For example, [@Mani](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91049/61001)s approach is flawed. `php` is not the only extension that allows the execution of php code. There is also `php4`, `php5`, `pht`, and so on. As it is very unlikely that an attacker can upload `php` files, but not `php4` files, you definitely need to block those as well.

Additionally, if an attacker can upload files to arbitrary directories, they can just upload an `index.php` file to `wp-includes` (which inherits the index.php allows from the root directory). And if we can assume that attackers cannot upload files to arbitrary directories, well, then we can just protect that one directory. Because of this, it is important to limit the allow to the current directory.

Comment: But, I has helped me to solve the problem by 60 ~ 70%.